# Content not within div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and my issue is that the content (ul) within the "forecastDiv" is not inside the "forecastDiv" border. The content stays inside the border once I remove Bootstrap's grid system but I need to align my content properly so I need to be using the grid system. Below is the code I have in a codepen (go to "6-day forecast" comment in HTML). Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

HTML

```
<div id="forecastDiv">

    <div class="col-md-1" id="boxInfo0">
        <p id="forecast0">0
        </p>

        <p id="forecast0TempC">0
        </p>

        <p id="day0">Test
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1" id="boxInfo1">
        <p id="forecast1">0
        </p>

        <p id="forecast1TempC">0
        </p>

        <p id="day1">Test
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1" id="boxInfo2">
        <ul id="forecast2">0
        </ul>

        <ul id="forecast2TempC">0
        </ul>

        <ul id="day2">Test
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1" id="boxInfo3">
        <ul id="forecast3">0
        </ul>

        <ul id="forecast3TempC">0
        </ul>

        <ul id="day3">Test
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1" id="boxInfo4">
        <ul id="forecast4">0
        </ul>

        <ul id="forecast4TempC">0
        </ul>

        <ul id="day4">Test
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1" id="boxInfo5">
        <ul id="forecast5">0
        </ul>

        <ul id="forecast5TempC">0
        </ul>

        <ul id="day5">Test
        </ul>
    </div>

</div> <!-- end forecastDiv -->
```

CSS

```
#forecastDiv {
width: 100%;
border: solid black;
margin: 0 auto; }
```

https://codepen.io/mcmaster-99/pen/ybWvyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a "container" or "container-fluid" class to your `<div id="forecastDiv">`.  "container" is a bootstrap class that will keep everything inside the div.

```
<div class="container" id="forecastDiv">
```

Comment: here's the bootstrap documentation on containers, they are required when you're using the grid system:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#containers

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it but now the content inside the div won't align to the center with margin 0 auto. :(